# requests.Response.text shows odd symbols

Tags: python, python-requests, ads

I use Python's `request` library to access (public) ads.txt files:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.sicurauto.it/ads.txt')
print(r.text)
```

This works fine in most cases, but the text from the URL above begins with some strange symbols:

```
> ï»¿google.com, [...]
```

If I open the URL in my browser, I do not see these three symbols; the text begins with `google.com, [...]` I am a beginner when it comes to encodings and web protocols ... where might these odd symbols come from?

Comment: it's a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify your encoding (in `r.encoding`) before calling `r.text`:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.sicurauto.it/ads.txt')
r.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'  # specify UTF-8-sig encoding
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14532226/4743630): Use 'utf-8-sig' encoding.