# Python - ï»¿ in front of an api response

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, fastapi, byte-order-mark

The response the API is giving me looks like this:

I am using FastAPI to send a post request to an API that returns an XML string:

````py
import requests
from fastapi import APIRouter, Response

router = APIRouter()

def __post():
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
    auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth("username", "password")
  
    response = requests.post('https://example.org/id', headers=headers, auth=auth)
    return response.text

@router.get("/{id}")
def test():
    xml = __post()
    return Response(content=xml, media_type="application/xml")

The response from here is:

```xml
"ï»¿<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n
...
````

As you can see, the characters `ï»¿` is added in front. I looked it up, and I can see it's something to do with encoding (`utf-8-sig`). I even tried to save the response to an xml file on the server:

```py
# Write response to file
with open('response.xml', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
     f.write(xml)
```

But the characters `ï»¿` is still added.

How can I parse the XML response withouth the characters `ï»¿`?

Comment: If it's coming from the server you probably have to strip the BOM (the `ï»¿`) from the front of the document (assuming that the data is being served with plain UTF-8 as the encoding).  The owner of the server needs to fix their encoding practices.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14532149/1346276

Comment: Using encoding `utf-8-sig` is specifically asking for the signature (BOM) to be added, so if you use that encoding you'll get the UTF-8 BOM as the first bytes of your file regardless. Using just `utf-8` (which is the default) should drop it - UNLESS - the original API you're querying adds those bytes; in that case you'll have to strip them yourself.